# How should I incorporate Like button in Android App with Facebook sdk 4?

Tags: android, facebook-like, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-sdk-3.0

I could only find [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button)
in facebook documentation. There are links to it from other pages too. What bugs me is that it is title "Docs/Android SDK/Deprecated/Like Button (Android v3)". Is it really deprecated? If so, what's the v4 of doing it?

Update:
I've accepted the answer because it links to the documentation ( Documentation: developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) - I don't know how I missed it. However, this is not working for me as I expected :-( I will try to investigate further..

Comment: LikeView is deprecated now. Please check [https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way of doing that is inserting a LikeView into the layout this way:

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
     android:id="@+id/like_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

After that you just have to configure the like button as you wish, getting it from the layout like this:

```
LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
    "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers",
    LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
```

Comment: This is how it reacts:

If facebook app isn't installed - it works.

If facebook app is installed but I am not logged in from the app - clicking the like button does nothing (the screen flickers, so maybe it opens and closes a dialogue).

If facebook app is installed and I am logged in from the app - shows a message near the button "Be the first of your friends to like this", but clicking the like button does nothing. 

Where is the documentation? Please help...

Comment: Did you modify the setObjectIdAndType function as you need? You need to specify what the link button is going to do (what publication is going to be liked).

About the logging session I'm thinking about checking if there's a session active, for instance:  if(Profile.getCurrentProfile()==null) ask for log in.

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: I use v4.35.0 and in the source code LikeView.java " * @deprecated
 * LikeView is deprecated"